# Determine whether DateTime was baked into Version of .NET assembly at compile time?

Tags: .net, datetime, assemblies, version, compile-time

How do I know that adding the Build and Revision values *of a given .NET assembly* to `new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)` will give me the compile time?

Put another way: how do I know that the `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]` attribute was used for the assembly at compile time?

Comment: erm... Build and Revision aren't the compile time, they're simply incrementing numbers identifying a particular version of a dll from any other version. They've got nothing to do with compile time.

Comment: and even if someone has such a convention to set them to those values, there is no way to verify that fact except by asking the people who built the assembly.

Comment: The 'assembly' tag is for low level programming, not for .NET assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The [`AssemblyVersionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx) just stores a bunch of numbers. Those numbers could be:

- Manually assigned
- Auto-incremented
- Based on date and time
- Based on source control revision numbers

There's nothing in `AssemblyVersionAttribute` to tell you this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
static string TimestampFromVersion(string version)
{
    string[] versionComponents = version.Split('.');
    DateTime potentialCompilationDate = (new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)).AddDays(versionComponents[2]).AddSeconds(2 * versionComponents[3]);
    return potentialCompilationDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
}
```

and check against the file's timestamp...